# Finding starting and ending offsets of a word (following by multiple punctuations) in a sentence

Tags: python, regex

```
text = 'how much are you pledging to spend on education?!'

p = re.compile('education?!')

print p.search(text)

None
```

But why? What's so special about a word following by multiple punctuations that makes re search not working?? I don't understand it :(

Comment: Why do you want start and end offsets anyway? That's rather unusual, there might be a better way for what you're actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`?` is a special character in regex, meaning "optionally match the preceding rule".  In this case, it's optionally matching "n", which is fine, but then expects the next character to be "!".

Instead, escape the "?" in the regex.  Now it matches "?" rather than acting as a special character.

```
p = re.compile('education\?!')
```

The [docs on the `re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) explain this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't appear to know regular expressions anyway and thus are unlikely to really want/need them, may I suggest this?

```
>>> text = 'how much are you pledging to spend on education?!'
>>> needle = 'education?!'
>>> start = text.index(needle)
>>> end = start + len(needle)
>>> start, end
(38, 49)
```

But what I really want to know is why you want start and end index. If you for example want them in order to replace that substring, there's a much better way:

```
>>> text.replace(needle, 'health care?')
'how much are you pledging to spend on health care?'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have meta characters that you want to match literally, you should use [re.escape](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) to help you escape them by prepending a `\` to all non-alphanumerics:

```
>>> text = 'how much are you pledging to spend on education?!'
>>> pat=re.escape(r'education?!')
>>> pat
'education\\?\\!'
>>> p=re.compile(pat)
>>> p.search(text)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(38, 49), match='education?!'>
```

This allows you to escape metacharacters in unknowns:

```
>>> [re.escape(w) for w in ('education?!', 'dog', 'cat?', 'ba\ll')]
['education\\?\\!', 'dog', 'cat\\?', 'ba\\\\ll']
```

There is a great discussion about the [backslash plague](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague) on the Python 3.4 re [HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#regular-expression-howto)

---

Based on comments:

```
>>> m=p.search(text)
>>> m.span()
(38, 49)
>>> text[38:49]
'education?!'
>>> text[slice(*m.span())]
'education?!'
```

Comment: I thought it was because of the backslashes but it is not. Why does re.search always gives a additional position in the ending offset